# Stop WordPress automatically showing <p></p> tags

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Wordpress automatically generate lot of unwanted `<p></p>` tags every where. Even the `img` tag also wrap by these `<p>` tags. So It's create unwanted white spaces in the site. I tried lot of ways to remove those tags:-

```
preg_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),array('',''),the_content(),1);

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content)
```

nothing works for me. First I want to know why those tags automatically generating? And How can I fix that?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-paragraph-tags-from-around-images/

Comment: remove the spaces at the place where `<p>` is created automatically or you can use `jQuery('p:empty').remove();`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wordpress Visual Editor itself create those tags for new lines.

You can try to remove the filter [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) from `the_excerpt` or `the_content`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
// OR
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Sometimes it doesn't work (Didn't work for me in the past. Not with PHP).

You can try with Javascript/jQuery, place this code after DOM loaded or before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
jQuery('p:empty').remove();
```

Will remove all empty `<p></p>` elements  from all over the document.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this plugin

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/
```

or else user this in theme's functions.php file

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the `remove_filter` function in the `after_setup_theme` hook. The reason been is that it might get overrun by later on by the content or excerpt. So you would use the function as follow

```
function remove_the_wpautop_function() {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_the_wpautop_function' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently discovered a pure HTML/CSS solution, you can wrap your code in pre tags, and add all:unset as a style, like this:

```
<pre style="all:unset"><!-- your HTML --></pre>
```

This will prevent wordpress from add 'p' or 'br' tags to your code and prevent it from adding unwanted styles through the pre tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of plugin to disable autop in WordPress or you can use following filter to remove autop:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

However, if you need to style and format content from wp-editor, you will not be able to do so if you have removed autop.

If you want to continue using autop functionality but want to remove empty p tag you can do it using jQuery.

I am able to remove unwanted empty p tags using following codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $ = jQuery; 
    $('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the theme editing area of WP admin.

Add this code to your functions.php file, and save it.

```
<?php
function my_formatter($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'my_formatter', 99);
?>
```

> Now, when writing a post/page, use [raw][/raw] tags to surround that
>   parts of the post/page that you do not want formatted.

OR

```
 <?php the_content(); ?>
```

and place this directly above:

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

it should look like this:

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('#^<\/p>|<p>$#', '', $content);
echo do_shortcode($content);
```

I tried it while using it in shortcode and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) will work fine-

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
  $in['wpautop'] = false;
  return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```